# How to validate a price (money amount) mySql decimal column in Yii?

Tags: activerecord, validation, yii

I am using a mySql **DECIMAL(12,4)** column to hold price values (seeing how that's what Magento uses). I want to [validate](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model#declaring-validation-rules) them in my ActiveRecord model using Yii's [CValidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CValidator) rules, but I'm not quite sure how to do it.

I assume I can do it with the [CTypeValidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CTypeValidator) set to "float", but I wanted to see how other folks are doing this. I don't see an actual "currency" validator. Maybe I should just validate the length?

```
array('price', 'type', 'type'=>'float'),
```

or

```
array('price', 'length', 'max'=>17), // 12 + 4 + . = 17?
```

Suggestions and examples? Thanks!

Comment: Another thought I had... what about a "max value" validator of 999999999.9999?

Comment: if you're sure that the maximum price will always be that specific amount, I see no problem :p except if you're building a 'product', maybe a shopping cart or whatever, who knows, maybe one of your user will be from a country with a ridiculously inflated currency :P

Comment: How about using NumberValidator?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I myself used the:

```
array('price', 'type', 'type'=>'float'),
```

rule... if needed, you can also use or combine the previous with the 'match' validator

```
array('price', 'match', 'pattern'=>'fancy regex magic here'),
```

Comment: Ah true, RegEx can certainly be made to do this... perhaps that's what I need to do to check the length.

Answer (score 5):

To add a working example, as this is common question (with no good answer in SO)"

```
public function rules(){
...
array('price', 'match', 'pattern'=>'/^[0-9]{1,12}(\.[0-9]{0,4})?$/'),
...
```

where {1,12} is the range of whole digits , and {0,4} is the range of "sub" units.

For a normal price range of 0.01 to 9999.99 use the regex like this:

```
'/^[0-9]{1,0}(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$/'
```

ref: [kitune in Yii forums](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/10880-solved-cnumbervalidator/page__view__findpost__p__143376)

Answer (score 0):

For number validation you can use:

```
array('price', 'numerical', 'integerOnly' => false, 'min' => 0),
```

If you need to restrict digits before and after decimal mark then use regex as others have suggested.